# Simple cost-benefit analysis

Tags: probability, arithmetic, economics

I am stuck at a very simple problem:

Suppose, I am running out of insurance, and as a result, I am incurring a the cost of A with event 1 + the cost of B with event 2.
Now, I go ahead and buy an insurance that will protect me from event 1, but will incur me a total cost of C. I will remain vulnerable to Event 2.
What is the total profit I am receiving from making the investment.

Logical calculation is,
Prior total cost: A+B
New total cost: B+C
Total profit: (A+B)-(B+C) = A-C

But my mind is constantly pesking me with the total profit to be: A-B-C.

I am essentially doing cost-benefit analysis.
Can someone please tell me where I am wrong?

I know my benefit function to be A, and not A-B. Please indicate what is wrong.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are events, what is the meaning of $A+B$? And if they are amounts of money, what is the meaning of the phrase "will protect me from A"?

Comment: They are specific events, incurring certain costs.

Comment: Then what is $A+B$?

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: What I do not understand that you haven´t mentioned any **probabilities** that event A or event B occur.

Answer (score 1):

Total cost incurred if no new insurance is bought: $A + B$.

By buying insurance, you incur cost $C$ no matter what, and incur:

1. No additional cost if event 2 does not occur.
2. Additional cost B if event 2 does occur.

So, under which of these two assumptions do you want to calculate the total profit?

Comment: Even if events 1 and 2 are probabilistic, event 2 can’t be saved even if it occurs. Will the event 2 still matter, in calculation of profit/benefit (cost is known already)?

Comment: Sure.  Let's say, event 1 is an earthquake, and event 2 is a flood.

Oh, btw, what do you mean by "incurring cost A with event 1"?  Does that mean, "if event 1 occurs"?

Comment: Yeah. Both events can be probabilistic. I wanted to keep everything simple. So ignored their probabilistic characteristic.

Comment: Actually, I think I can explain myself in this way, when I am investing I should look into finding all possible benefit that I am generating from that investment. If I invest into earthquake measure, my revenue stream should be benefit from earthquake measure, and not flood measure. Observe, in this case our marginal benefit to be A. And the profit to be incremental change happened to our life, I.e., A-C.